# How to send file using Request Python with some headers?

Tags: python

I tried to send file with some headers like:

```
files = {'file': (file, open(file, 'rb'), {'Content-type': 'multipart/form-data; boundary=---BOUNDARY', 'Authorization' : 'Basic ' + api_key})}

r = requests.post(base_url, files=files)
```

Server returned 401 error that means absent header `Authorization`. But I sent it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Basic Authentication you can follow the [requests docs](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/). It's visible on the very first line of code in the example on that page.

Use the `auth` keyword argument to supply a 2-tuple of username and password:

```
response = requests.post(base_url, files=files, auth=('username', 'password'))
```

**Edit:**

If you want to send actual headers, rather than things like Basic Auth, you can do that with the `headers` keyword argument. This allows you to give a dict of headers you would like to send. For example:

```
headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}\
response = requests.post(url, data=data, headers=headers)
```

The `auth` argument, should be a simplification of the above because Basic Auth is so common, but don't quote me on that one.

Comment: I asked about headers, not about Basic Authentication, also your code does not work too

Comment: API says to send token in header when I attempt upload file

Comment: @Oleg Good to know it works, edited answer for headers anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You can follow this example to take it from the official documentation I think you should try it first in postman, with the json then and do it from python.

This information is taken from the official documentation
[python](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/)

Comment: This is better to be a comment , because this is not actual answer , this is a test approach.